# "While" and "when" difference

Tags: grammar

Can I interchange while and when in the following sentences?

1- He waited **while/when** I combed my hair.

2- He was waiting **while/when** I was combing my hair.

Comment: Not without loss of meaning. However, maybe you can answer a question for me -- why do ELL folks keep substituting one word for another and asking if they're the same?

Answer (score 1):

"While" and "when" can have essentially the same meaning. However, 'when' is better for situations that do not have an ongoing duration; 'while' is appropriate for an ongoing action or period of time. In some sentences they are not interchangeable without a subtle shift in meaning.

*I ate when I was hungry.* (I got hungry, so I ate). 'While' would imply that I continued eating only as long as my hunger lasted.

*He came over when I told him to.* (He came as soon as I told him to, or at a specific time that I named.)

*They graduated when they were 18 years old.* ('While' could imply that the graduation was just hours before they turned 19, but the ceremony happened during the time they were still 18.)

Comment: Maybe an easier way to explain it: "When" is "at a specific time"; "while" is "during a time period"